# Create UnityEngine.Plane from UnityEngine.GameObject Plane

Tags: visual-studio, unity-game-engine, mesh

Maybe a simple one but i can't get it right.
I created a plane in the Editor -> 3D-Object -> Plane.
The user can interact with that plane.

But in code I need the `UnityEngine.Plane`, not the `UnityEngine.Gameobject`.

I learned that I can't do `GetComponent<>()` because Plane is a struct, not a component.

But how can I convert the Gameobject Plane I have to a `UnityEngine.Plane` or create a new Plane with that?

I found [this](https://answers.unity.com/questions/474726/cannot-convert-type-unityenginegameobject-to-unity.html), but I don't know how this would help me.

Comment: If your general problem is `create a new Plane` than you can use [Instantiate](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.Instantiate.html) to create a clone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you misunderstood what `UnityEngine.Plane` is.

From [Unity Documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Plane.html) :

> Representation of a plane in 3D space.

Just like a Vector3 or a Quaternion, this is not a primitive Mesh and is not a 3D Mesh at all. You cannot convert your Plane GameObject to this struct.

What you can do is create a representation of your plane mesh to do some calculations with it. But you won't be able to instantiate a new plane with it.

If you want to create a plane that represents your plane GameObject, you can call the constructor of UnityEngine.Plane with some data from your `MeshRenderer` and `MeshFilter` of your Plane GameObject.

```
var filter = GetComponent<MeshFilter>();
Vector3 normal;

if(filter && filter.mesh.normals.Length > 0)
    normal = filter.transform.TransformDirection(filter.mesh.normals[0]);

var plane = new Plane(normal, transform.position);
```

This should give you a plane representation of your plane GameObject, looking in the same direction and going through the position of your plane.

Comment: Deprecated. Better use https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.CreatePrimitive.html

Answer (score 1):

You are right, Plane the primitive is not the same thing as Plane the struct.

To create UnityEngine.Plane, use its constructor 
https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Plane-ctor.html

In its simplest point it looks like this

```
Plane plane=new Plane(Vector3.up, Vector3.zero);
```

Up signifies the normal vector of the plane (in this case I am assuming you want the plane to be horizontal, so 'looking up', the second vector is a point through which the plane must pass (in this case zero, as I assumed you want the plane to be level with ground).